# RLS policy one vote per user per question

Tags: postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

I am struggling with creating an **RLS policy** that makes sure, **every user can vote just once per question** (in my case, a question is a bill).

The `vote` table lists users and bills. Every user can vote for every bill once:

```
| id | user_id | bill_id | vote       |
| -- | ------- | ------- | ---------- |
| 1  | 25      | 12      | yes        |
| 2  | 38      | 12      | yes        |
| 3  | 12      | 12      | no         |
| 4  | 62      | 8       | abstention |
```

I tried following policy where error **Error updating policy: failed to update pg.policies with the given ID: missing FROM-clause entry for table "new"** is thrown.

```
CREATE POLICY vote_once_policy ON vote
  FOR INSERT
  WITH CHECK ((
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vote
    WHERE bill_id = NEW.bill_id AND user_id = NEW.user_id
  ) = 0);
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Or is there another way to ensure that each user can only vote once per bill?

Thank you in advance for your appreciated feedback.

Supabase RLS Policy editor:
[image: Supabase RLS Policy editor]

Supabase vote table:
[image: Supabase vote table]

Comment: You don't use a RLS policy for this but rather a unique constraint.

Comment: RLS can't enforce uniqueness, only a unique constraint can. Your query that counts the number of records can only see committed records, nothing that is in flight.

Comment: Thank you @frank-heikens for your appreciated comment that helped to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments of the question, RLS can't enforce uniqueness, only a **unique constraint** can. The query that counts the number of records can only see committed records, nothing that is in flight. (thanks to [@frank-heikens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271959/frank-heikens) and [@bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi))

The constraint could looks as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE vote ADD CONSTRAINT unique_vote_per_user_per_bill UNIQUE (bill_id, user_id);
```

Comment: Creating a unique constraint automatically adds an index, you don't need to create another one yourself

Comment: From the manual: `Adding a unique constraint will automatically create a unique B-tree index on the column or group of columns listed in the constraint.`. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS

Comment: Thank you guys, I removed the index part.